# Database not working on actual Ubuntu Touch Device

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I'm currently developing an application for Ubuntu Touch. It already has some basic functionalities and utilizes localstorage/SQLite. When running directly from the Ubuntu SDk itworks fine but when I create a click package and install it to my actual device the database doesn't seem to work. I thought it's related to the security groups but I already added almost all of them except the media groups but still no luck.

My device is a Nexus 7 2013 and i install the click package through the following commands since Install to device functionality doesn't work in Ubuntu SDK app.

```
sudo pkcon install-local filename
sudo click register --user=phablet packagename  version
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally solved my problem... all I have to do is to make sure the `name` property of my mainView is the same as the `name` field in my manifest file.

That's it...thanks for those who considered answering my question :)